# Зачем нужны explicit копирующий и перемещающий конструкторы?

Tags: c++

Зачем нужны explicit копирующий и перемещающий конструкторы?

```
struct A {
  explicit A(const A&);
};
```

Comment: Для записи `A b{a};`, но не `A b = a;` :)